# How to check multiple checkbox in jquery php code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below are my Jquery code which selects only one checkbox and unchecked other, I want to check multiple checkboxes in category filter.
Flow starts from getShopByCatData() the it filters category with function name filterCategory()

Can anyone please provide some guidance how to check multiple checkboxex here.

**Steps -**

1. Search on website with keyword "Hunter".
   It will show results on which multiple category the part is available.
2. Click on any category for e.g. Traditional then check only Traditional category and it will hide other categories that time.

I want to show all categories even if user checked only one so other category should remain as it is. Then user should be able to check multiple categories as well and multiple category result should display.

Jquery code -

```js
const getShopByCatData = function() {
  var strHTML = '<div class="filter-title">Category</div><ol>';
  if (this.arrShopCat != 'undefined' && typeof this.arrShopCat != 'undefined') {
    totalItem = Object.keys(this.arrShopCat).length;
    var filterBid = $('#filtercat').val();
    var categoryPage = $('#categorypage').val();
    var cls;
    var strDisable = '';

    if (categoryPage) {
      // strDisable = 'disabled=disabled';
    }
    for (i = 0; i < totalItem; i++) {
      cls = '';
      if (filterBid == this.arrShopCat[i].id) {
        cls = 'checked=checked';
      }

      strHTML += '<li><input getShopByCatData type="checkbox" ' + cls + ' ' + strDisable + ' onclick="javascript:filterCategory(' + this.arrShopCat[i].id + ', this,0)"><span style="color:#545A5E;padding-left:2px;">' + this.arrShopCat[i].name + '</span>' + this.getCatChildHTML(this.arrShopCat[i]) + '</li>';
    }
    strHTML += '</ol>';
  }
  return strHTML;
};

const getCatChildHTML = function(arrCategoryInfo) {
  var childHTML = '<ol>';
  titem = Object.keys(arrCategoryInfo.childs).length;
  var cid = $('#filtercat').val();
  for (c = 0; c < titem; c++) {
    cls = '';
    if (cid == arrCategoryInfo.childs[c].id) {
      cls = 'checked=checked';
    }
    childHTML += '<li><input getCatChildHTML type="checkbox" ' + cls + ' onclick="javascript:filterCategory(' + arrCategoryInfo.childs[c].id + ', this,' + arrCategoryInfo.id + ')"><span style="color:#545A5E;padding-left:2px;">' + arrCategoryInfo.childs[c].name + '</span></li>';

    // console.log("getCatChildHTML >> "+ childHTML);
  }
  childHTML += '</ol>';
  return childHTML;
};

const filterManufacturere = function(brand, chkBrand) {
    if (chkBrand.checked) {
      $('#filterbrand').val(brand);
    } else {
      $('#filterbrand').val(0);
    }
    $('#pageno').val(1);
    // this.sendR(1);
  };
  
const filterCategory = function(category, chkCat, parent) {
    if (chkCat.checked) {
      $('#filtercat').val(category);
    } else {
      $('#filtercat').val(0);
    }
    $('#parentcat').val(parent);
    $('#pageno').val(1);
    // this.sendR(1);
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>
    <input getshopbycatdata="" type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:filterCategory(2102, this,0)"><span style="color:#545A5E;padding-left:2px;">Ceiling Fans</span>
    <ol>
      <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:filterCategory(2103, this,2102)"><span style="color:#545A5E;padding-left:2px;">Top Selling</span></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:filterCategory(2110, this,2102)"><span style="color:#545A5E;padding-left:2px;">Indoor</span></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:filterCategory(2106, this,2102)"><span style="color:#545A5E;padding-left:2px;">Low Profile</span></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:filterCategory(2105, this,2102)"><span style="color:#545A5E;padding-left:2px;">Traditional</span></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:filterCategory(2107, this,2102)"><span style="color:#545A5E;padding-left:2px;">Casual</span></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:filterCategory(2111, this,2102)"><span style="color:#545A5E;padding-left:2px;">Children's</span></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:filterCategory(2108, this,2102)"><span style="color:#545A5E;padding-left:2px;">Decor Specific</span></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:filterCategory(2109, this,2102)"><span style="color:#545A5E;padding-left:2px;">Outdoor</span></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

[![Current checkbox filter][1]][1]

Comment: Please click `[<>]` and post a [mcve] with RENDERED HTML, CSS and Script. If there is no issue with PHP or SOLR, please remove those tags. If the AJAX works, remove that too and just show an example of the object

Comment: remove tags and added code in snippet. some functions are interrelated thats why added those function

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML to the snippet.

Comment: You have one question. You show a huge amount of unrelated code. Please post a ***[mcve]*** - and if possible rename jQuery to $ to make it easier to read

Comment: Ok Sir, added related html code. I am not sure now which code is useful here or now and which code should I have remvoed. I have kept Jquery functions and HTML Code for now.

Comment: Step by step to recreate? What to click and what is expected outcome?

Comment: Steps updated please check above.

Comment: Sorry. I am not going to debug your site. If you cannot produce a [mcve] with three checkboxes here, then never mind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223005/discussion-between-rahul-and-mplungjan).

Comment: updated code with html and minimal example

Comment: I tried to fix your snippet. It does not seem to do what you expect

Comment: can u please provide your way code which can help me to check multiple checkboxes